# Creating one many to many table that is reused for many different tables when they all have a relationship to the same entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a table [Team] in my Database. Many other tables require a many to many relationship with this table. This is mostly due to various records in my other table having authorisation settings based on which team the current user is in.

For example a record in my [User] table can be linked to many teams and a team can be linked to many [Ticket] records. If the teams overlap that user now has permission to view the [Ticket].

I am considering two options, firstly have a seperate table for each [UserTeam] and [TicketTeam] e.g ticket team will have the following columns `Id,TicketId,TeamId`.

My second option is to store the data for both in the same table. To do this I would create a [AuthorisationRecord] table with one `Id` column and a [AuthorisationRecordTeam] table with `Id,AuthorisationId,TeamId`. I would also then need an extra column on my [Ticket] and [User] tables `AuthorisationRecordId`. This has the downside of needing an extra column and every time we create a record we also have to create an [AuthorisationRecord] record.

If it was just these two tables I think it would make sense to have a seperate many to many table for each. However as there are many tables needing this same relationship with the [Team] table and the potential for many more in the future I am leaning toward my second option, as this will simplfy the devlopment process as every time we add a new feature that needs authorisation based on the Team we will not have to add another many to many table but simply add one extra column with a relationship to my [AuthorisationRecord] table.

My question is weather this is a good scaleable idea? It seems like it will greatly simplfy my database as instead of potentialy hundreds of many to many tables with my [Team] table there will be just one. However I can't find resources online about this potential method so I think it might be a bad idea.

Comment: Many to many relationships in table can get really messy. Is there no way you can use a junction table to deal with this? If you aren't familiar with these, read up on them a little, and keep the data as normalised as possible.

Comment: Although it doesnt answer your direct question, are you aware of SQL Servers built in row level security https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669076(v=vs.110).aspx ? It might be useful background info.